# Angular 5 Mat-grid list responsive

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

i created grid list with column 6 and i want to be grid title take 100% width on small screen devices. Now it creates 6 column on small screens as well

Expected:
One grid-title occupies 100% of space on mobile device only

Comment: Please add your code to your question.. otherwise it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You have to set the `cols` attribute of the `mat-grid-list` dynamically depending on the screen width. You'd have to decide on which width breakpoint will the `mat-grid-list` render the 1-column version.

HTML:

```xml
<mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="2:0.5" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>5</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>6</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

TS:

```typescript
ngOnInit() {
    this.breakpoint = (window.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1 : 6;
}
  
onResize(event) {
  this.breakpoint = (event.target.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1 : 6;
}
```

[**Stackblitz demo here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-mat-grid)

Comment: Checkout flex layout

Comment: A better width would be `480`

Comment: this is the fastest and shortest solution - I changed it a little to simply use in both cases `innerWidth / 300` which returns me multiple columns for my responsive web...

Comment: What if I want 2x1. Means I need to two grid title or cards in a single row in mobile screens and three on pad and laptop screens?

Comment: how about `this.breakpoint = Math.floor(event.target.innerWidth / 200);`

Answer (score 37):

I liked [Altus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48499719/3415716), but I would like to have more breakpoints. So I've created a simple method with some breakpoints using FlexLayout ObservableMedia service instead of onResize:

```js
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MediaChange, ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatGridList } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
})
export class GridComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('grid') grid: MatGridList;

  gridByBreakpoint = {
    xl: 8,
    lg: 6,
    md: 4,
    sm: 2,
    xs: 1
  }

  constructor(private observableMedia: ObservableMedia) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.observableMedia.asObservable().subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      this.grid.cols = this.gridByBreakpoint[change.mqAlias];
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Breakpoint: {{grid.cols}}</span>
<mat-grid-list #grid rowHeight="2:1">
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>5</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>6</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>7</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>8</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-responsive-material-grid-leocaseiro

Comment: doesnt work on first load. (tried it on a mobile phone). only if i change orientation to horizontal and back to vertical, it fixes the number of columns shown

Comment: ObservableMedia was deprecated in 7.0.0-beta.19 and removed in 7.0.0-beta.23. you need to use MediaObserver instead

Answer (score 16):

You may use the following directive if you need a reusable solution:

```js
 
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatGridList } from '@angular/material';
import { ObservableMedia, MediaChange } from '@angular/flex-layout';

export interface IResponsiveColumnsMap {
  xs?: number;
  sm?: number;
  md?: number;
  lg?: number;
  xl?: number;
}

// Usage: <mat-grid-list [responsiveCols]="{xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 4, lg: 6, xl: 8}">
@Directive({
  selector: '[responsiveCols]'
})
export class ResponsiveColsDirective implements OnInit {
  private countBySize: IResponsiveColumnsMap = {xs: 2, sm: 2, md: 4, lg: 6, xl: 8};

  public get cols(): IResponsiveColumnsMap {
    return this.countBySize;
  }

  @Input('responsiveCols')
  public set cols(map: IResponsiveColumnsMap) {
    if (map && ('object' === (typeof map))) {
      this.countBySize = map;
    }
  }

  public constructor(
    private grid: MatGridList,
    private media: ObservableMedia
  ) {
    this.initializeColsCount();
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeColsCount();

    this.media.asObservable()
      .subscribe((changes: MediaChange) => 
        this.grid.cols = this.countBySize[changes.mqAlias]
      );
  }

  private initializeColsCount(): void {
    Object.keys(this.countBySize).some( 
      (mqAlias: string): boolean => {
        const isActive = this.media.isActive(mqAlias);

        if (isActive) {
          this.grid.cols = this.countBySize[mqAlias];
        }

        return isActive;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I used a BreakpointObserver to achieve this.

See angular documentation : https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  cols : number;

  gridByBreakpoint = {
    xl: 3,
    lg: 3,
    md: 3,
    sm: 2,
    xs: 1
  }

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    this.breakpointObserver.observe([
      Breakpoints.XSmall,
      Breakpoints.Small,
      Breakpoints.Medium,
      Breakpoints.Large,
      Breakpoints.XLarge,
    ]).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.matches) {
        if (result.breakpoints[Breakpoints.XSmall]) {
          this.cols = this.gridByBreakpoint.xs;
        }
        if (result.breakpoints[Breakpoints.Small]) {
          this.cols = this.gridByBreakpoint.sm;
        }
        if (result.breakpoints[Breakpoints.Medium]) {
          this.cols = this.gridByBreakpoint.md;
        }
        if (result.breakpoints[Breakpoints.Large]) {
          this.cols = this.gridByBreakpoint.lg;
        }
        if (result.breakpoints[Breakpoints.XLarge]) {
          this.cols = this.gridByBreakpoint.xl;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
}
```

```html
<mat-grid-list #grid [cols]="cols" rowHeight="20:11" gutterSize="20px" >
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>5</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>6</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>7</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>8</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by the answer from Grégory.

If you wish to avoid explicitly subscribing to an observable you can use an async pipe.

```js
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent {

cols$: Observable<number> = this.breakpointObserver
  .observe([Breakpoints.Small, Breakpoints.XSmall])
  .pipe(
    map((result) => {
      if (result.breakpoints[Breakpoints.XSmall]) {
        return 1;
      } else if (result.breakpoints[Breakpoints.Small]) {
        return 2;
      } else {
        return 3;
      }
    }),
    shareReplay()
  );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
  }

  
}
```

```html
<mat-grid-list [cols]="cols$ | async" rowHeight="20:11" gutterSize="20px" >
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>5</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>6</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>7</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>8</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Great work everybody!

I made some further improvements to Алексей Сердюков's Answer:

- updated for flex-layout 7.0.0+
- when resizing the window, the directive under some circumstances returned the wrong count

Gist @ GitHub: https://gist.github.com/mzellho/7fc7d5bd52a29948c47911a993547dad

Answer (score -1):

Addition to the @Leo Caserio' s answer, if you get an error on the first load as follows:

> Error: mat-grid-list: must pass in number of columns. Example: ...

You can use `subject`:

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('grid',{static:true}) grid: MatGridList;
cols:Subject<any> = new Subject();

constructor(private observableMedia: MediaObserver) { }

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.observableMedia.asObservable().subscribe((change: MediaChange[]) => {
      this.cols.next(this.gridByBreakpoint[change[0].mqAlias]);
    });
  }
```

**Template**

```
<mat-grid-list #grid [cols]="cols | async"  rowHeight = "1:1">
```

**Note:** @angular/flex-layout": {"version": "8.0.0-beta.26" }